# Does the data loaded using jquery is considered as a part of HTML source code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

**search.php** Is a web page contain a form with select boxes and a button and it's separated in two parts

```
---------------------------------------------
                                             |
                      1                      |
                                             |
                  Form with                  |
               input type button             |
                                             |
                                             |
----------------------------------------------
                                             |
                    2                        |
                                             |
         when I click on the button           |
        I display data from database         |
             using jquery without            |
           refreshing the database           |
                                             |
---------------------------------------------
```

1. Is an HTML form with same fields that should be filled by the user and a button.
2. When the user clicks on the button, I call lod_date.php to load data from database to the specific place using jQuery

The data loaded is presented in an HTML table with 5 columns and one of them is surounded by `<a>` tag

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
column1     column2      column3    <a href='#' class='basic'>column4</a>      column2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Because I want after clicking on the link to get the related detail of the specific row
(in dialog box using JQuery UI)

But the problem is when I click on the link of a specific row, my script can't detect a  tag.

When I show the source code in Firefox, the `<div>` which should contain my HTML table still without content but the HTML table with data is shown. I find the loaded data  as a response when I verify with Firebug.

When we load data to our page using jQuery is it considered as a part of our page source code? How can I detect when a user clicks on the link?

(I'm using PHP and SQL Server)

```
<div id="container">
<div class="data"></div>
<div class="pagination"></div>
</div>
```

Data should be showen between `<div class="data"> here where my tabel should be </div>`and when i press a button, i load this content :

```
$msg .= "<tr>
    <td>" . $row['column11'] . "</td> " .
    "<td>". $row['column12'] . "</td>" .
    "<td>".$row['column13']."</td>".
    "<td>".$row['column14']."</td>".
    "<td><a href='#' class='basic' >".$row['columns5']."</a></td>".    
    "<td>".$row['column6']."</td>".
    "</tr>";
```

The problem is when i try to clik on the columns5, even if i click on it, nothing is happened!

Comment: Is it a Dom manipulation. It may differ a little.

Comment: @Goikiu, can you explain more please ?

Comment: The source code is a thing. But when you change on realtime with Javascript something you use the Dom Manipulation. On browser with webkit like Chrome you can see the differences.

Comment: exactly, i have an empty div,when i clik on the button i load data into this div.Becuase i show an HTML table inside this div. and one of this columns is considered as an <a> tag, because i want after cliking on a specific row on this column to show teh detail

Comment: You can "detect" the click with Jquery maybe with a handler on the basic class.

Comment: Can you guide me please, because i dont see what do you mean

Comment: Something like $(document).on('click','basic',function(){//Do something});

Comment: it gives me an error : TypeError: $(...).live is not a function
$('#container .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem as follow :

1. I changed this line of source code : `<td><a href='#' class='basic' >.$row['columns5'].</a></td>`   by this one   `<td>".$row['operateur']."<img src='search.png' class='imagesdetail' id='". $row['sens'] ."' ></td>` . (the idea behinde this change, to use an image instead of URL : more beautiful).
2. Accessing the image using JQuery : `$('#container .data table tbody tr td img').live('click',function(){ ajaxCall($(this).attr('id'));})`
3. ajaxCall() : get data from database and put it into JQuery UI Dialog in load.
4. I had also a problem of Jquery version, as i have an old version i have to use `live('click',function(){...})` (**live** function) it was a source of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate/update html using any means ,no problem .Only the resulting html should be proper and tags should be properly closed.

So if you write `<a href="javascript:alert('Hello World');">click me</a>` in html page and click it,it will surely display an alert message.

I would recommend to use Chrome Developer tools-Console tab to check ,and re-check for your html format for any unclosed tag/javascript errors.

**EDIT**

change your a to `<a href='javascript:alert('Hello World');'>` .
load your content ,in chrome use inspect on `<div class="data"></div>` ,see the inner contents to figure out issue.

Comment: I agree with you, but there are twho separated files, first one (search.php) who contain my empty div and another file(load_data.php) from where i load my data from database and i present it in HTML table inside the dive located in (search.php). my goal is to manipulate the DOM from the search.php

Comment: First, have you tried using "Chrome Developer tools" to see contents of <div> as mentioned in your question.Chrome will give you complete HTMl with all new data.

Comment: Im using Firefox and Firebug, when i see the source code of my page and verify the div (i find nothing inside), but the data is loaded and displayed !! with Firebug i check the response and i finde the table

Comment: that's why am asking you to plz try "Chrome Developer tools" to get exact html.so u can figure out problems with the html.

Comment: when i inspect the html file, i find the content of the table i find all my <td></td>, <td></td>,... all the table elements

Comment: post inner html contents, mention the anchor tag which is not working.

Comment: you can chek the whole post now